# Mouse & Touchpad lost on/off toggle

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I upgraded to 16.04LTS and was thrilled to see my Mouse & Touchpad application had an on/off toggle.  After an upgrade (or perhaps from installing libinput) the toggle disappeared again.
How can I get it back?  Can you show me the code to uninstall libinput, or downgrade xinput, if that might help.  Excuse my naivety.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Mouse *&* Touchpad application can be replaced by Mouse *and* Touchpad at Ubuntu Software.
I haven't tried it out yet, but that looks promising.

Comment: But the new app does absolutely nothing to mouse or touchpad.

Comment: Both ("M&P" and "M and P") are working now that libinput is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove libinput by

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

The GUI tool does not work with libinput installed.

You can toggle the touchpad by a terminal command.

```
xinput disable <id>
```

You can find the `<id>` of your touchpad in output of `xinput`.

Comment: Removing libinput fixed it thanks!  Mouse and Touchpad now working well again. There are lots of posts saying libinput is the way of the future, but for now it seems easier to go without.